# Python packages not originating from filesystem

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import

In the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) describing the import system, there is the following (emphasis done by me):

> [...] You can think of packages as the directories on a file system and modules as files within directories, but don’t take this analogy too literally since **packages and modules need not originate from the file system**. [...]

What options are there for storing modules and packages that do not correspond to files and folders, respectively, in the filesystem?

I [read](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) about the possibility of loading modules and packages from zip archives. Is this one of the possible options that the quoted paragraph refers to?
Are there any other such options?

Comment: If the answer gave you a solution, you may accept it. Other peers may find this question/answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way you can think about packages and modules but **it is not mandatory that a package/module is a directory/file in file system.**

You can store a package/module in a zip file and load it with zipimport.

You can load a module from a string variable:

```
import imp

code = """
def test():
    print "function inside module!"
    """

# give module a name
name = "mymodule"
mymodule = imp.new_module(name)
exec code in mymodule.__dict__

>>> mymodule.test()
function inside module!
```

Comment: Yes, I read about importing a package from a zip file. I guess custom module loaders can be created that could load modules regardless of their origin. Is this right?

Comment: Yes! They do not need to exist in file system.